# How to update $SU(2)$ Higgs fields with Heat Bath algorithm?

Tags: higgs, quantum-chromodynamics, interactions, bosons, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm trying to update the Higgs field coupled with a pure gauge $SU(2)$ theory through Heat Bath algorithm. Pure gauge and Higgs configurations should be updated separately. For the pure gauge part the heat bath is the same of $SU(2)$, with the difference that in the staple calculus there is a quadratic interaction term of the form $2k \phi_{x+\hat{\mu}}\phi_{x}^{\dagger}$. While for the Higgs update, one in principle must extract the four Higgs components of the field from the distribution: $$dp(\phi_j)\approx d\phi_j \exp{\left(-\xi \left( \phi_j-\frac{V_j}{\xi}\right)^2 \right)},$$ where $j=1, 2, 3, 4$ and $V_j$ represents the NN interaction. My question is: how to perform an algorithm that extracts the Higgs components directly from this distribution?

One of the articles is the following: https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1167